# How to get Quarter from a date in Firebird SQL

Tags: date, firebird, datepart

I can easily get total sales in this month and previous month.

```
SELECT ‘This Mount’,  SUM(Price) FROM Sales 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM OrderDate) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)   
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM OrderDate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)   
Union All
SELECT ‘Previous Month’,  SUM(Price) FROM Sales 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM OrderDate) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE)   
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM OrderDate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
```

I want to get the total sales in this quarter and previous quarter.

Getting quarter from a date is very easy with MS-SQL as follows:

```
SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER, @date)
```

How can I do this with Firebird?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use DECODE function in conjunction with EXTRACT:

```
SELECT
  DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM <date_field>),
    1, 'I',
    2, 'I',
    3, 'I',
    4, 'II',
    5, 'II',  
    6, 'II',  
    7, 'III',  
    8, 'III',  
    9, 'III',
    'IV')  
  FROM
    <some_table>
```

Or just

```
  SELECT
    (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM <date_field>) - 1) / 3 + 1
  FROM 
    <some_table>
```

Comment: `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM <date_field>) / 3 + 1`
This doesn't work. Because (December) 12/3 + 1 = 5

Comment: Fixed. Should extract 1 from a month number.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dates,
   EXTRACT(MONTH from dates) as SalesMonth, 
   floor(((EXTRACT(MONTH from dates)-1) / 3.0 + 1))  as QTR 
from CustomerPO 
where ((dates > '1/1/2016') and (dates < '12/31/2016')) 
order by dates
```

Here, 'dates' is the field name of Order table 'CustomerPO'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dates,
   EXTRACT(MONTH from dates)            as SalesMonth, 
   ceil(EXTRACT(MONTH from dates) / 3)  as QTR 
from CustomerPO 
where ((dates > '1/1/2016') and (dates < '12/31/2016')) 
order by dates
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes